# Css after the text going out of the box

Tags: html, css

I have a wired problem, i have a regular nav with ul and li and i am trying to make after one of the li red box with number inside, but the problem is that the number from some reason going out of the box, what is the problem?

[image]

This is the code:

```
#mainHeader .rightNav {
  float: right;
  li {
    position: relative;
  }
  img {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  li:nth-child(4)::after {
    content:attr(data-value);
    color:#fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #d94a3e;
    text-align: center;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ys7Wy3EJPlA4VlXDt6hE?p=preview

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I cant because of some reason in fiddle this work fine when i does not make the all program, i hope that someone with experience maybe will know what cause of this wired behavior.

Comment: anyways share the fiddle..it will be helpfull..

Comment: Here you see the text in the after element is out of the box: http://plnkr.co/edit/ys7Wy3EJPlA4VlXDt6hE?p=preview

Comment: add line-height: 18px; to  li:nth-child(4)::after

because there is line-height you have set as 45px already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was wrong on your line height.

Should have : `line-height: normal;`

Add that to `#mainHeader .rightNav li:nth-child(4)::after`

Update your css to this:

```
    #mainHeader .rightNav li:nth-child(4)::after {
      content: attr(data-value);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background-color: #d94a3e;
      text-align: center;
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      line-height: normal;
    }
```

[Sample link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ogSmlsU3cXsONAxSSWly?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your styles with this:)

```
#mainHeader .rightNav li:nth-child(4)::after {
      content: attr(data-value);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background-color: #d94a3e;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: -10px;
      right: 0;
      padding: 1px 4px;
}
```